# Really cheesy, huh?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, rhyme

> I scamper away at any sound,
>
> I'm the thing next to your desktop, waiting to be found.
>
> Change one letter and you are in me,
>
> Add one letter, take a spoonful,
>
> Yum! What a beauty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> mouse.

> I scamper away at any sound,

> That's what mice do.

> I'm the thing next to your desktop, waiting to be found.

> That's the mouse of the computer.

> Change one letter and you are in me,

> We are all in houses!
>  *Or* "Youse" is an actual word, and "you" are in it.

> Add one letter, take a spoonful,

> Mousse is a type of dessert.

> Yum! What a beauty.

Comment: Ah, really close. Mouse is the correct word though, but think about the change one letter and you are in me bit. And no, you don't need to delete s.

Comment: Quick Clarification: In the line you are wrong in, 'you' as in the person you, and me as in the new word :)

Comment: @Stevo Is the word in that line rot13(lbhfr)? It is an actual word ([merriam-webster link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/youse)), and has "you" in it.

Comment: So, I had 2 answers for that line, one was that, one was another. Either way, you got the word right (mouse)

Comment: But not giving checkmark when both are found :)

Comment: Clue: You are probably in it right now.

Comment: @Stevo Oh, is it rot13(ubhfr)?

Comment: yes! it is! good job!

Comment: Just fix it up and checkmark!